# SSRS : New calculated field based on where condition

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm new to SSRS reporting and I'm need of help...

I have a dataset with fields "Process", "Level" and "Workweek"

```
Process Level  WW
------- -----  --
Test    Lvl_0   3
Test    Lvl_1  28
Test    Lvl_2  48
Samp    Lvl_0  10
Samp    Lvl_1  39
Samp    Lvl_2  51
```

What I want now is to create two more calculated fields called **Start_WW** and **Pro_Start** that has the values from **WW** field.

WW of Lvl_0 is considered to be the Process_Start.

the logic is something like

```
Process Level  WW Start_WW Pro_Start
------- -----  -- -------- ---------
Test    Lvl_0   3    0       3
Test    Lvl_1  28    3       3
Test    Lvl_2  48   28       3
Samp    Lvl_0  10    0      10
Samp    Lvl_1  39   10      10
Samp    Lvl_2  51   39      10
```

I know it is similar to SQL

> Update Table SET Start_WW=(Select WW from Table where Level='Lvl_0') where Level='Lvl_1'
>
> Update Table SET Proc_Start=(Select WW from Table where Level='Lvl_0')

I'm not sure how to write the expression for it. Pls help me.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Start_WW` is simply the previous `WW` then you don't even need a calculated field; you can just use the `Previous()` function in the expression for the table's cell:

```
=IIF(Fields!Process.Value = Previous(Fields!Process.Value), Previous(Fields!WW.Value), 0)
```

For the `Pro_Start`, you can add this to your SQL:

```
SELECT MyTable.Process, MyTable.Level, MyTable.WW, Start.Pro_Start 
FROM MyTable 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Process, Level, MIN(WW) AS Pro_Start 
    FROM MyTable 
    GROUP BY Process, Level
) Start ON MyTable.Process = Start.Process AND MyTable.Level = Start.Level
```

With no access to the query, then you can get `Pro_Start` via a [Lookup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx):

```
=Lookup(Fields!Process.Value, Fields!Process.Value, Fields!WW.Value, "MyDataset")
```

The `Lookup()` will return the first instance of the `Process` and give you the `WW` of that row.

Comment: I tried using `Previous()` but I get the data of other process as start of my next one which is not right.

Comment: `case fields!ww.process when previous(fields!ww.process) then Previous (fields!ww.value) else value`

Comment: It worked for `Start_WW`. My dataset is a shared dataset and I can't access the query designer. so how to go about `Pro_Start`now. And also, instead of 0 in `Lvl_0` of `Start_WW` will I be able to enter a value say **Lvl_1.Value-4weeks**? is it possible?

Comment: Added a way to get Pro_Start. I don't think you can do what you want with the `Start_WW` on `Lvl_0` as there is no `Next()` function like the `Previous()` function. You should open a new question on that specific question to see if anyone has some ideas on how to do that.

Comment: I posted a new question regarding the **Start_WW**. for `Pro_Start` I'm getting error in the `Lookup()` for the last parameter saying `the value expression has a scope parameter that is not valid for lookup function. the scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is the name of a dataset`. any help on solving this?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I had the dataset and result field parameters swapped - try the syntax shown now