# SSRS : calculated field based on other field and condition

Tags: reporting-services, expression

This is a question that is related to my previous one. pls kindly refer to it

[SSRS : New calculated field based on where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625721/ssrs-new-calculated-field-based-on-where-condition/26625804#26625804)

the final table now looks like

```
Process Level  WW Start_WW Pro_Start
------- -----  -- -------- ---------
Test    Lvl_0   3    0       3
Test    Lvl_1  28    3       3
Test    Lvl_2  48   28       3
Samp    Lvl_0  10    0      10
Samp    Lvl_1  39   10      10
Samp    Lvl_2  51   39      10
```

Now what I want is instead of 0 in **Lvl_0** of **Start_WW** will I be able to enter a value say `Lvl_1.Value-4weeks?` is it possible?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you tell me what is 4weeks ?? in "Lvl_1.Value-4weeks"

Comment: `4 weeks` is a constant. if the value of **Start_WW** of Lvl_1 is say 12. I want value of Start_WW of **Lvl_0** to be 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.You can do it. Add new calculated field. You can write IIF condition. Something like **=IIF**(Fields!.Level.Value=**"Lvl_0"**,**" Lvl_1.Value-4weeks "**,Fields!.Level.Value).